# When can we shift the subject in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

When can we shift the subject in a sentence?

We are not supposed to shift the subject:

Shift—“ We have reached a point where ‘one’ ought to face the possibility of a sudden change.”

Better—“ We have reached a point where ‘we’ ought to face the possibility of a sudden change.”

But, is it all right to switch subjects in these kind of sentences?

“He was in a bad mood, still looking around, when his glance met hers.”

“‘Hate’ was an awful word for her that her brain could not retain.”

Or we have to be consistent:

“He was in a bad mood, still looking around, when he glanced at her.”

“‘Hate’ was an awful word for her that could not be retained by her brain.”

Comment: Neither of the second pair are very well constructed (using 'glance' twice). He was still in a bad mood, unsettled, when his glance met hers.

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast! But I was about to edit it.

Comment: You are missing that separate clauses can always have different subjects: 
“He was in a bad mood ... **when his glance met hers**.” Also: "He was no longer tan **when the suitcase finally got shipped back from Hawaii**."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerns about shifts in person or tense aren't usually grammar violations but just confusing writing style. For instance: "Justin pushed open the door. Inside the room he sees a treasure chest." Both sentences are valid, but the switch from past tense to present makes the narrative confusing. Similarly, I could say "We should learn from our mistakes" or "One should learn from their mistakes," but "One should learn from our mistakes" is confusing. The problem here is that both pronouns are meant to refer to the same thing, so they should be consistent.

In your examples, you use different pronouns *to refer to different people*. Nothing wrong with that; you could combine as many as you want. "He swept the floor while she washed the dishes, we set the table, and you cooked the food." (Though that's a fake example; in practice, it might be hard to set up so much context that it would be clear who each of those pronouns refers to. But they all refer to different entities, so they're okay.)

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense.

Comment: I read this sentence in a grammar book: Shift—“Although some people consistently arrive on time, there are others who do not.” Is it fine? Or should be “…, others do not.”

Comment: @Piermo, it is completely fine, and more natural. The second form _others do not_ is grammatical, but reads as rather formal.

Comment: @Colin Fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Piermo Hm, I'd argue that the first feels slightly more formal, but at any rate both are fine. These two clauses are just connected in the same sentence, but they're not a "series." For a series it's important to stay consistent. E.g. "Yesterday I mowed the lawn, read a book, and a friend came over for a visit" would be bad. Because this series takes the form "I [verbed]," so you have to imagine "I" as being able to start all the things in it, and you wouldn't say "I a friend came over."